# Unsure how to perform this List Transformation in Scala optimally

Tags: scala

Does anyone know a good way to turn the following inputList into the desired output list below?

The function I am seeking to create

```
def transformList(input:List[(String,String)]):List[(String,String)] = ???
```

input

```
val inputList = List(
    ("class","testClass1"),
    ("class","testClass2"),
    ("id","testId1"),
    ("class","testClassRepeat"),
    ("class","testClassRepeat"),
    ("id","testId2"),
    ("href","testHref1")
)
```

desired output

```
List(
    ("class","testClass1 testClass2 testClassRepeat testClassRepeat"),
    ("id","testId1 testId2"),
    ("href","testHref1")
)
```

I have a solution, but I don't think I am doing it in a good/efficient way. The solution I currently am using is:

1. Create an empty mutable map
2. Loop through the inputList with a .foreach
3. Pushing key/values based on the inputList into the mutable map. Then appending to the values of existing keys if applicable (for example, there are 4 "classes" in my inputList example.)

Thanks,
Phil

Comment: Use `sortWith`, `groupBy` and `mkString` -- no mutability required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use groupBy and can be done in one line.

```
   scala> inputList.groupBy(_._1).
          map{ case (key, value) => (key, value.map(_._2).mkString(" "))}.toList

    res0: List[(String, String)] = List(
                                       (href,testHref1), 
                                       (class,testClass1 testClass2 testClassRepeat testClassRepeat), 
                                       (id,testId1 testId2)
)
```

Comment: I am using this solution. Thanks. I was hoping there was a one line solution out there.

Answer (score 9):

```
def f(xs: List[(String, String)]): Map[String, List[String]] = 
    xs.foldRight(Map.empty[String, List[String]]){ 
          (elem: (String, String), acc: Map[String, List[String]]) =>
             val (key, value) = elem
             acc.get(key) match {
                case None     => acc + (key -> List(value))
                case Some(ys) => acc.updated(key, value :: ys)
             }
    }

scala> f(inputList)
res2: Map[String,List[String]] = Map(
       href -> List(testHref1), 
       id -> List(testId1, testId2), 
       class -> List(testClass1, testClass2, testClassRepeat, testClassRepeat)
     )
```

Answer (score 5):

Maybe `groupBy()` is what you are looking for?

```
scala> inputList.groupBy(_._1)
res0: Map[String,List[(String, String)]] = Map(
         href -> List((href,testHref1)),
         class -> List((class,testClass1), (class,testClass2), (class,testClassRepeat), (class,testClassRepeat)),
         id -> List((id,testId1), (id,testId2))
      )
```

It's also pretty straightforward to clean up the list of tuples while we are at it, eg.

```
scala> inputList.groupBy(_._1).map(kv => (kv._1, kv._2.map(_._2)))
res1: Map[String,List[String]] = Map(
         href -> List(testHref1),
         class -> List(testClass1, testClass2, testClassRepeat, testClassRepeat),
         id -> List(testId1, testId2)
      )
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use foldLeft on sorted collection:

```
def transformList(input:List[(String,String)]):List[(String,String)] =
  input
    .sortBy(_._1)
    .foldLeft(List[(String, String)]()) {
      case ((xn,xv)::xs, (name, value)) if xn==name => (xn, xv + " " + value)::xs
      case (xs, item) => item::xs
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way with a for comprehension but using also `groupBy` (see @hezamu):

```
val m = 
  for { (k, xs) <- inputList.groupBy(_._1)
         s = xs.map(_._2).mkString(" ")
      }
  yield k -> s
```

and then

```
m.toMap
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `groupBy` with `for comprehension` to make the code more inline with the relational SQL concepts wherein the result you need is analogous to a `Group By` on key and then transforming the grouped result, in this case concatenating the string:

```
def transformList(input:List[(String,String)]):List[(String,String)] = {
  (for {
    // Return the generator for key-values of grouped result
    (k, v) <- input.groupBy(y => y._1)
    // For every list in the grouped result return the concatenated string
    z = v.map(_._2).mkString(" ")
  } yield k -> z)
  .toList
```

}